# Why Angular Js Parameter of a Watch Function Should Be a Scope Variable?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.myFunc = function(privilege){ 

    $scope.check = function(privilege){
       return ...
    };  

    $scope.$watch('check(privilege)',function(val){
        ...
    }    
}
```

My privilege variable becomes undefined at every watch check(which must not be)? Why I should define it scope variable or do I miss anything with Angular Js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first parameter of the [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method (the "watchExpression") can be either an Angular string expression (that is evaluated against the $scope), or a function, which is called with $scope as the first parameter.  There is no way to pass `privilege` as the first argument to a watchExpression that is a function.

You could create a closure, if you don't want to store the `privilege` value on the $scope.  See [Vojta's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/w39eL/) for an example.
See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/UJRxn_Y0Dd4/9ha38PC3PCwJ